# Django Models: The default value for booleanfield did not get set in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

Django: 11.1
MariaDB: 10.2.6

In models.py, I set a boolean field as follows:

```
class myClassName(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mytablename'
        verbose_name = 'name'
        verbose_name_plural = 'names'
        ordering = ['myid']

(several fields defined here...)

myField = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='name', default=True, help_text='some help here')                                           
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.myid)
```

Then, do 'makemigrations' and 'migrate'

Afterwards, I can see the table well defined in MariaDB, however default values are not set for the BooleanFields. The fields are defined as tinyint(1), Default=NULL.

Do I need to set some other value in the field definition, in order to properly configure the default value in the database?

Update 11/07: I see the same issue with a char field. The default value is set as Null in MariaDB table. I can manually change the default value, but I don't know why Django doesn't set it for me.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('xyz', '040_something'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='myfield',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, default='any', help_text='Some help', max_length=255, verbose_name='myfield_verbose'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: No, you do not.